# How to create multiple childs in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project where I need to send data to firebase an a specific manner:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Codes').child(firebaseUser.uid).child(className);
```

However, I can not send the data using this piece of code. How do I send data through two child locations.

Comment: what is the structure of your json in firebase?

Comment: use need to use a method that _sends_ data to the realtime database such as `set` or `update`, for example. You can send a chuck of JSON at once, i believe, and you can also send an array of stuff at once.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such kind of problems while learning firebase but I managed like this in Kotlin.

```
var database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                var userClass = User()
                userClass.id = user.uid
                userClass.name = user.displayName
                userClass.email = user.email
                userClass.imageUrl = user.photoUrl?.toString()
                userClass.phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber
                database.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(userClass)
```

firebase.child returns FireBaseReference setValue puts the value to the reference.Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

To write an object to a location:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Codes').child(firebaseUser.uid).child(className);
ref.set({ key1: "value1", key2: true })
```

To write values to two completely different paths in the database, use complete paths as the keys:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
var updates = {};
updates["Codes/"+firebaseUser.uid+"/"+className] = "value1";
updates["Otherpath/child/key2"] = true
ref.set(updates)
```